# Recursive, Variadic Template Function

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++17, template-meta-programming

I know I could do that with a regular variadic function, but I would like to do that with templates. My (C++17) compiler would not agree to it.

```
#include <cstdint>

unsigned int fct(unsigned int k)
{
    return k;
}

template<std::size_t First, std::size_t... Other>
unsigned int fct(unsigned int k)
{
    return First * fct<Other...>(k);
}

int main(void)
{
    //const auto k = fct<3u, 5u, 7u>(2u);
    return 0;
}
```

Above code compiles fine. If I choose to uncomment the declaration of `k` however, compilation fails with the report below:

```
foo.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
foo.cpp:17:13: warning: unused variable ‘k’ [-Wunused-variable]
  const auto k = fct<3u, 5u, 7u>(2u);
             ^
foo.cpp: In instantiation of ‘unsigned int fct(unsigned int) [with     long unsigned int First = 7; long unsigned int ...Other = {}]’:
foo.cpp:11:30:   recursively required from ‘unsigned int fct(unsigned int) [with long unsigned int First = 5; long unsigned int ...Other = {7}]’
foo.cpp:11:30:   required from ‘unsigned int fct(unsigned int) [with long unsigned int First = 3; long unsigned int ...Other = {5, 7}]’
foo.cpp:17:35:   required from here
foo.cpp:11:30: error: no matching function for call to ‘fct<>(unsigned int&)’
  return First * fct<Other...>(k);
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
foo.cpp:9:14: note: candidate: template<long unsigned int First, long unsigned int ...Other> unsigned int fct(unsigned int)
 unsigned int fct(unsigned int k)
              ^~~
foo.cpp:9:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
foo.cpp:11:30: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘First’
  return First * fct<Other...>(k);
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
```

How can I make this work? I thought that creating a non-template `fct()` would do the job.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
template<std::size_t First>
unsigned int fct(unsigned int k)
{
    return First * k;
}

template<std::size_t First, std::size_t Second, std::size_t... Other>
unsigned int fct(unsigned int k)
{
    return First * fct<Second, Other...>(k);
}
```

See it on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aF0H8Ee3cGRdpMQs). Another alternative is [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Q76uWd6jDXkJnOo3), as suggested by @chtz in the comments to the answer.

---

The *problem* is that the following function isn't a function template:

```
unsigned int fct(unsigned int k)
{
    return k;
}
```

Therefore, when `Other...` is an empty parameter pack, you have a call that is equivalent to:

```
return First * fct<>(k);
```

But it doesn't match any of your definitions. Think at it:

- The first function isn't a template one, so it doesn't match.
- The second function requires at least one argument, so it doesn't match.

Thus the error.

Comment: Much easier: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Q76uWd6jDXkJnOo3 But this question is a duplicate

Comment: @chtz Good point. Can I use your link in the answer (with mention)?

Comment: sure. (more characters due to comment-limit)

Comment: Thank you to you both, I marked this thread as solved.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is tagged C++17, you may want to try the newly introduced [fold expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) ([live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ne6xUEPwSd2qqqUq)).

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t... Args>
auto fct(std::size_t k) noexcept {
  return (k * ... * Args);
}

int main() {
  std::cout << fct<>(1) << std::endl;
  std::cout << fct<2, 3>(1) << std::endl;
}
```